# Scrapy does not get full product name, replace some character with commas?

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm using scrapy to get product name and price on tmall, a chinese e-commerce site. The code is pretty simple, but when it scrapes the name, it replaces some part of the product name with commas. For the example below I typed in "ipad air 3", and the first product's name is "Apple/苹果 10.5 英寸 iPad Air". The "10.5 英寸 iPad Air" part is displayed in the different color, I think it's because it matches with the search keyword. But I'm not sure why scrapy gets ",,,,," for that part of the product name. Does anyone know potential ways I could try to fix it?

To sum up, the result I want to get is "Apple/苹果 10.5英寸 iPad air"; however,the result I'm getting is "Apple/苹果 ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '".
Here are the screenshots:
[web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5Vj8.png)
[result i'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aKjB.png)

```
items = TmallspiderItem()
product_info = response.css('.product-iWrap')

for product in product_info:
    product_name = product.css('.productTitle a::text').extract()
    product_price = product.css('.productPrice em::text').extract()
    items['product_name'] = product_name
    items['product_price'] = product_price
    yield items
```

Comment: Instead of images of code, can you please paste the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<a href="//detail.tmall.com/item.htm?id=612529092115&amp;skuId=4486436443940&amp;standard=1&amp;user_id=2202421911399&amp;cat_id=2&amp;is_b=1&amp;rn=c9a973f4c51d2bf839339810354ff07a" target="_blank" title="Apple/苹果 Apple/苹果 10.5 英寸 iPad Air" data-p="8-11" >
Apple/苹果 Apple/苹果 <span class=H>10.5</span> <span class=H>英寸</span> <span class=H>iPad</span> <span class=H>Air</span>
</a>
```

As you can see, the name you're trying to get is split accross multiple `span` elements.
Your css selector only selects the text nodes which are direct children of the `a` element, so it won't get the contents of those.

You could modify the selector to get all the descendants instead and join those, but I would recommend using the `normalize-space()` xpath function instead.

```py
>>> product.css('.productTitle a::text').extract()
['\nApple/苹果 ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '\n']
>>> product.css('.productTitle a ::text').extract()
['\nApple/苹果 ', '10.5', ' ', '英寸', ' ', 'iPad', ' ', 'Air', '\n']
>>> product.css('.productTitle a').xpath('normalize-space()').get()
'Apple/苹果 10.5 英寸 iPad Air'
```